# How to make boxes contain the same size and scrollable using tailwindcsss

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

```
 <div className="overflow-x-auto p-5 gap-5">
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    <div className={` bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
  </div>
```

According to the doc `overflow-x-auto` will make this horizontal and scrollable. Which does not work?

[image]

It is just vertical as it is and how can I make this horizontally scrollable? `flex` makes them horizontally listed but then it reduce the size and does not make it scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex-shrink-0` to the child elements in order to make them avoid reduced size.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="overflow-x-auto flex p-5 gap-5">
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
  <div class="bg-orange-700 flex-shrink-0 w-[300px] h-[300px]"></div>
</div>
```